# RDL file runtime design viewer VS 2013 or RDL file Header viewer without data source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reporting-services, rdl

I need to open RDL files runtime without any data source. It's for just load and check Header configurations with colors. No need to load data. But every RDL files should be loaded with header details. how could i do that? is any possibility to do ?

Comment: Do you want to open reports deployed on a report server or do you have a directory containing all the reports?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin : Thanks , I want to open any rdl file like Report Designer . Program dosen't know about dataset , datasource  or any Report server. But in RDL files may include dataset names and datasource.

Comment: Actually i'm not a .Net expert. I'm a PHP programmer. I want to know this facility is available in .Net or not. I have tried many times using my .Net 2013 tool.

Comment: When you say you want to load, you mean programmatically check or display an empty report?

Comment: just a example: think you have some RDL files. I need to view that report header with colors using my tool. But my system dosent know about your datasource or report server.

Comment: I think the best way is to write an application that parses the XML and check if the colors are ok.

Comment: See my answer to know where to look at

Answer (score 0):

RDL files are standard XML files so you would just need to parse those files and find header details.

Header information is located in `Report` => `ReportSections` => `ReportSection` => `Page` => `PageHeader`.

Then you can read/update the required tags.

Comment: I think you still didn't understand my question. I don't need to view XML row data. I want to view all RDL files like when you are opening those in "Report Designer".

Comment: @RoshanPerera - There is nothing out-of-the box to render only the header part of a report. That's why I'm telling you that the best approach is to check in the RDL file content. It contains all the information so depending on your needs you could either check the items color or create an application that renders only the header. Of course, if you tell us *why* you need this and *what* you need to check we could provide a more accurate solution.

Comment: Actually I created a tool for attributes replacement like font-name,color,back-color etc.. in RDL files. I already don this part and I had to work with XML reading part also. Now i want to show to user report design changes before and after. RDL files may be "simple report" , "Form Report"  or "cross-tab" type. So its very difficult to create a custom report viewer control. if you are opening any RDL file in your "Report Designer" , its opening without asking datasource and can see colors too. so i need the same in runtime. Actually thanks for the answering this.